# Where is Erlang Term Storage (ETS) stored?

Tags: erlang, ets

Hi I am learning Erlang.

I read from http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ets

> Erlang has something called ETS (Erlang Term Storage) tables. ETS tables are an efficient in-memory database included with the Erlang virtual machine. [...]

My question is: The Erlang term data stored in ETS tables - Where are they stored? Are they temporarily stored in my computer's memory? If I restart my application, will they disappear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [ETS](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) are RAM based and will disapear when the owner process terminates.
- [DETS](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html) are disk-based version of ETS. Being "disk-only" they are slow.
- For more advanced usage, you should take a look at [Mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html), the standard Erlang DBMS.

[The documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/tablesDatabases.html#id68365) has some basic comparisons between those three options.